# Do not pass deploy on DigitalOcean using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digital-ocean

I'm doing according to the [instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma), but still doesn't work.

Server writes that I don't have a symbolic link to the file **database.yml**

```
00:03 deploy:check:linked_files
ERROR linked file /home/demo/myproject/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on 188.226.140.17
```

[I read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28987373/8063677) what need to create file **database.yml** manually
I create database.yml

```
touch /home/demo/myproject/shared/config/database.yml
```

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: myproject_db
  username: postgres
  password: 1234567890postgres
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  min_messages: WARNING
```

Further, he writes that there is no symbolic link to the file **secrets.yml**:

```
00:03 deploy:check:linked_files
      ERROR linked file /home/demo/myproject/shared/config/secrets.yml does not exist on 188.226.140.17
```

Created **secrets.yml** on the server

```
touch /home/demo/myproject/shared/config/secrets.yml
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rake secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.

development:
  secret_key_base: 1bbe19e548182eb986995dfef00bb0bb0ed410e25c8cdbf4e9f2e92290ce69f91b84c0fa76fdd50a18d49fea3906f57a0cba9398562fa39492a3472b680d8112

test:
  secret_key_base: ed1b6e6ca1dfd6c1b939414ffd69fa92dadfeb61fe7e819ac7d08c515a169f8648ec29b21e89a34d8649585916b6485dfc74f9eded1ecf83a87e315500e1b64a

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Further he writes that there is no symbolic link to the file ** nginx.conf **:

```
00:03 deploy:check:linked_files
      ERROR linked file /home/demo/myproject/shared/config/nginx.conf does not exist on 188.226.140.17
```

About the **nginx.conf** file
 [Tutorials DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma)  it is written that it is necessary to create the symbolic link a little in other place, not in that in which it is specified at me in an error, and in occasion of **secrets.yml** it is told at all.
The path in my server:

```
/home/demo/myproject/shared/config/nginx.conf
```

The path is written in [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma):

```
sudo ln -nfs "/home/deploy/apps/appname/current/config/nginx.conf" "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appname"
```

I substitute the name of my user for the command instead of **deploy** and instead of **appname** the name of my application. It turns out:

```
sudo ln -nfs "/home/demo/apps/myproject/current/config/nginx.conf" "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject"
```

still writing an error:

```
00:03 deploy:check:linked_files
      ERROR linked file /home/demo/myproject/shared/config/nginx.conf does not exist on 188.226.140.17
```

Then I create not a symbolic link, but a file ** nginx.conf **

```
touch /home/demo/mypoject/shared/config/nginx.conf
```

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/demo/apps/myproject/shared/tmp/sockets/myproject-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/demo/apps/myproject/current/public;
  access_log /home/demo/apps/myproject/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/demo/apps/myproject/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

***And here begins the most interesting!*** When i try to pull gems with Gemfile - deploy hangs. I thought at first that this was the way it should be, but after a long wait I realized that something wasn't right.

```
00:21 bundler:install
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --gemfile /home/demo/myproject/releases/20170525093300/Gemfile --path /home/demo/myproject/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

I then tried to execute this command on the server directly.

```
~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --gemfile /home/demo/myproject/releases/20170525093300/Gemfile --path /home/demo/myproject/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

It seems to go further, but again began to give errors:

```
00:31 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: []
      01 /home/demo/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
      01 /home/demo/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
```

I execute this command on the server:

```
demo@test8CPU:~$ ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

But I have Gemfile in repository on Github and in my project!
I'm googling and find related questions
[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469015/capistrano-could-not-locate-gemfile-error-on-application-deployment)
[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453076/capistrano-could-not-locate-gemfile-or-bundle-directory)
[third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271342/ruby-on-rails-capistrano-could-not-locate-gemfile-error-when-running-cap-produ)
but they didn't help. Still the same error.


Help me please. I'm newbie.

Comment: For your information, never post secret_key_base and passwords anywhere. If possible try to replace with placeholders. You may edit the answer

Comment: @AkashPinnaka this data is fake

Comment: Then that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
demo@test8CPU:~$ ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

It's very simple. You're not in app folder. Previous commands worked because they had arguments like `--gemfile` and `--path`.
`bundle exec` doesn't have such arguments.

The solution is

```
cd /home/demo/myproject/current

~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```